# Swift 3: UITableViewCell Update RSSI

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a `UITableView` with a list of `CBPeripheral` once I perform a scan. When You click on the row, the app will connect to the `CBPeripheral` and the `Destination` view is given the `CBPeripheral` once it connects.

The `Destination` view is another `UITableView` with a list of `CBService`. On this view I have a custom header with information about the `CBPeripheral`. I would like to update the `RSSI` label on that custom header cell without having to `tableView.reloadData()`.

I tried adding the `peripheral.readRSSI()` in the cell itself but the delegate `peripheral(peripheral:didReadRSSI:error)` never seems to get called.

What I doing wrong? Can this not be done this way?

Any help appreciated.

**Destination View**

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ServicesTableViewController: UITableViewController, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    var peripheral: Peripheral?
    var sectionHeaderHeight: CGFloat = 110

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let peripheral = peripheral {
            peripheral.delegate = self
            peripheral.readRSSI()
            peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table View

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return peripheral?.services?.count ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        guard let services = peripheral?.services else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ServiceTableViewCell", for: indexPath)

        let service = services[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = service.uuid.description
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = service.uuid.uuidString
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return false
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ServiceHeaderTableViewCell") as! PeripheralTableViewCell

        if let peripheral = peripheral {
            cell.setupWithPeripheral(peripheral: peripheral)
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return sectionHeaderHeight
    }

    // MARK: - Peripheral Delegate

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        print("Did discover services")

        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Discovered service:\n \(String(describing: peripheral.services))")
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

**PeripheralTableViewCell**

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class PeripheralTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, CBPeripheralDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var NameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var UUIDLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var RSSILabel: UILabel!

    func setupWithPeripheral(peripheral: Peripheral) {
        NameLabel.text = peripheral.name ?? "No name"
        UUIDLabel.text = peripheral.identifier.uuidString

        if peripheral.state == .connected {
            print("Is connected... attempt to read RSSI")
            peripheral.readRSSI()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    // MARK: - Peripheral Delegate

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didReadRSSI RSSI: NSNumber, error: Error?) {
        print("Did read RSSI")

        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("RSSI: \(RSSI)")
            RSSILabel.text = RSSI.stringValue

            if peripheral.state == .connected {
                //peripheral.readRSSI() \\ turn this into a timed call
            } else {
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You will need to use a `Timer` to periodically issue a `readRSSI` command and then update the data based on the delegate call back

Comment: @Paulw11 I intend to do that, but the first call never seems to read it. Are you saying that call may fail to read?

Comment: @Paulw11 to test your answer, and placed it n a timer, I do see the timer does first, but the delegate is never called

Comment: Are you setting the cell as your peripheral's delegate?

Comment: Doh! You are right! Adding this now!

Comment: @Paulw11 ok through the console I can see that it's being ready, but the label doesn't change. Any help?

Comment: @Paulw11 another problem is when I do make the cell the delegate, the delegate `peripheral(peripheral:didDiscoverServices` in the  `ServicesTableViewController` doesn't get called. I assume that's because the delegate got changed of course =)

Comment: Right.  I wouldn't make the cell the delegate or perform any Bluetooth operations in the cell. The cell should simply be displaying information. I would have a Bluetooth manager that posted a notification when various Bluetooth events occur. Other classes can then subscribe to those notifications. For example an RSSI update would be received by the table view controller which would determine the row for the peripheral that was updated and then reload that row

Comment: @Paulw11 ah, I can reload a row? That's good. In my case it's only for first header row. I'll look into that tomorrow. If you can provide an answer with some helpful code or provide a small sample project that would be great!